# WebBrowser Control / Single Thread Apartment Help - .NET

Tags: .net, multithreading, webbrowser-control

I understand IE WebBrowser control is a COM object that runs in a single thread apartment and thus cannot be easily threaded.   My question is if two completely separate applications make a call to this COM control, does each get its own thread or does it handle both on the same thread behind the scenes in the core IE engine?

An example would be I have Test.EXE that does nothing more than process an extremely large website (let’s assume it takes a single thread 3 minutes to process).  If I open this 30 times, would all 3 instances be still working in a single thread, thus not really speeding up the time it takes to process 30, or would each get its own thread / instance of IE and in theory process all 30 in about the same time it processes a single one?

I tried testing this and the more threads I add, the slower each seems to go (Even before my processor comes near maxed.  My ram is not even a fraction).

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# WebBrowser Control in a new thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269800/c-sharp-webbrowser-control-in-a-new-thread)

Comment: Hans: This is not a duplicate because that is speaking about how to do it within a single application. I am already aware of the STA issue so I needed to know if you run this in multiple applications what the results would be

Comment: Somebody else reading this question might appreciate doing it in one process.  Who wouldn't?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were stating my question was a duplicate of that question.  I was just stating they were be 2 very separate problems.  Thanks for the link though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each application runs in its own process, so will have its own copy of the WebBrowser control. They cannot interfere with each other.

Comment: John:  I do understand they will definitely have their own copy of WebBrowser Control, however behind the scenes is this copy 100% unique?  Example would be if I open up 15 copies of Notepad, absolutely nothing is shared between them.  However if I keep attempting to open Outlook, they still share the instances with the core app that was opened.  Is there any way to know that even though each WebBrowser is "Unique", it's not sharing 90% of the resources with the core IE engine?

Comment: When you keep attempting to open Outlook, Outlook sees that there is already an instance open and tells the other instance to open a new window; it then exits. This is totally different, and no, there will be no writable memory in common between them.

Comment: John: Was just trying to give an example to explain what I meant.  But I appreciate it and I will assume everything is 100% unique to that specific application.

Comment: The code and read-only data will no doubt be shared. But those don't matter in the context of your question. Even in your Outlook example, nothing is shared across instances - there is only one instance.

Answer (score 1):

The WebBrowser control is a wrapper around the IE in-process COM server. This means that it will be loaded into each process which uses it. Each process will be able to communicate with it using its main thread.

Comment: Kol: as I wrote under John, that is more so my question.  Since it is just a Wrapper, does each process share the same main memory pool with the main engine or do each get a completely different instance of this engine?  Even though all 30 of these threads are using a unique instance of the COM object, do they still end up using a shared main instance once it reached the IE Engine?

Comment: I wrote a scriptable website tester program last year which uses WebBrowser. There were cases when I had to run in parallel more than one instances of it on the same PC, and I never experienced interference between them. So I guess there is no shared memory between WebBrowser instances in different processes.